# How to call view for Form in HTML template

Tags: python, html, django

I want to make an HTML template in which I want to make three forms(A, B and C). 
**A** form should load as default and having two buttons to open form B and C. A form should call view. **A** and grab data.

Now on button click Form **B** should be load and Fetch data from view. **B** as same for **C**

```
<form name='A' > 
    //should call view.A 
    button B <-- should call Form B and form B grab data from B 
    button C <-- should call Form c and form C grab data from C 
</form>
```

I do not know this is possible or not. 
Please Help.

Comment: There's no reference to your attempts. You should provide the code you are using and explain what is not working. Please have a look at StackOverflow best practice for asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: When form B appears, Form A should disappear or not?

Comment: yes when B call A should disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can technicaly do that using one view and one template to render the 3 forms, and then have an action url refering to 3 separate view like this:

```
def 3_forms_view(request):
    form_a = YourFormA(request.POST or None)
    form_b = YourFormB(request.POST or None)
    form_c = YourFormC(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "form_a": form_a,
        "form_b": form_b,
        "form_c": form_c,
    }
    return render(request, '3_form_template.html', context)

def view_a(request):
    form_a = YourFormA(request.POST)
    if form_a.is_valid():
        #do something
        form_a.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('your_succsess_url')
    # in case the form is not valid call back the view 
    # which handle the 3 form display
    return 3_forms_view(request)

def view_b(request):
    form_b = YourFormB(request.POST)
    if form_b.is_valid():
        #do something
        form_b.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('your_succsess_url')
    # in case the form is not valid call back the view 
    # which handle the 3 form display
    return 3_forms_view(request)

#same thing for view c
```

the **3_form_template**:

```
<form action="{% url 'view_a_url_name' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form_a.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Submit A</button>
</form>
<form action="{% url 'view_b_url_name' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form_b.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Submit B</button>
</form>
<form action="{% url 'view_c_url_name' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form_c.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Submit C</button>
</form>
```